# How to show up dialogue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have code of HTML of div tag which i have to show up using jQuery

Directory Lookup
        All fields required unless otherwise noted as optional.
            Search

error
                    Fill the required field.
                
                
         
                
                
                    error
                    No results found. Please try your search again.

when click on this link of code

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <a href="#" id="OpenDialog24" class="inline">Directory Lookup</a>   
    </div>
```

and i have write this code of jquery

```
$('#saveandcontinue').click(function(){
        alert("h");
         $('body').css('background', '#999');
        $('.footer').css('background', '#999');
        $('.utility-nav').css('background', '#999');    
        $('#savedialog').show("slow");         
    });
    });
    $('#close24').click(function(){
             $('body').css('background', '#fff');
            $('.utility-nav').css('background', '#fff');
            $('.footer').css('background-image','url(img/footer/footer-bg.png)');
            var text=$('#popuptext').val();         
            $('#savedialog').hide("slow");

        });
```

but it is only shows like an hide and show not like an dialogue box.
here is an example how my code is working right now - http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_hide_show

and what i want is you can see here - http://jsfiddle.net/zjRga/357/

Please suggest me where i am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First do not trust w3schools to show correct information

If you want to use the jquery-ui library like the fiddle is using to make the floating dialog box just include the jquery-ui js file into your page and call `.dialog()` with the options you want, [api documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/)

```
$("#savedialog").dialog({
  //options would go here
});
```

otherwise if you want to do it without a library you would need to set the elements position to like fixed and set their top,left,bottom, or right styles.

so you could add a class to your css like below

```
.dialog {
   width:200px;
   height:200px;
   position:fixed;
   top:50%;
   left:50%;
   margin-left:-100px;
   margin-top:-100px;
}
```

and add that to the class list on the element

```
<div id="savedialog" class="dialog"></div>
```

and then just show and hide the element when needed.

You would need extra javascript to make it draggable.

Comment: @SanjayRathod then you would need the second part of my code and setup the css style and apply it to the element, then you just have to show and hide

Comment: means you are saying that i have to apply the css of dialogue which is mention in your answer and aplly it

Comment: yea, just add `class="dialog"` to the element in your html, and make sure you have made the class in your css file.